# google+ for android ( getting null pointer)

Tags: android, google-plus

I am trying to incorporate Google+ for Android by going through [this official google
documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/android) . After following the steps given:

1. Dwnload latest SDK
2. Using Android 4.4.2,
3. Configured Eclipse to use Java 1.7( though it's  saying to use 1.6, I am guessing it's not my issue)
4. Then Enabled the Google+ API by providing `Package.Name` and `Sha1`. Then I configure the sample [app](https://github.com/googleplus/gplus-quickstart-android)
   and attached google-play-services_lib(imported) to it.

Now when Im running the app it is giving Exception in MainActivity's

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
    .addApi(Plus.API, null) // here the exception (nullPointerException) 
    .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN).build();
```

I m running it on physical Device Android 4.1.2.

Going through Google but didn't get any luck.

**LogCat:**

`05-27 10:23:46.808: D/ActivityThread(11136): setTargetHeapUtilization:0.25
05-27 10:23:46.808: D/ActivityThread(11136): setTargetHeapIdealFree:8388608
05-27 10:23:46.808: D/ActivityThread(11136): setTargetHeapConcurrentStart:2097152
05-27 10:23:47.228: D/AndroidRuntime(11136): Shutting down VM
05-27 10:23:47.228: W/dalvikvm(11136): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x411eb438)
05-27 10:23:47.228: E/AndroidRuntime(11136): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-27 10:23:47.228: E/AndroidRuntime(11136): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mygoogleplus/com.example.mygoogleplus.GooglePlusMainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Null options are not permitted for this Api
05-27 10:23:47.228: E/AndroidRuntime(11136):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2114)
05-27 10:23:47.228: E/AndroidRuntime(11136):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2139)
05-27 10:23:47.228: E/AndroidRuntime(11136):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:143)
05-27 10:23:47.228: E/AndroidRuntime(11136):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241)
05-27 10:23:47.228: E/AndroidRuntime(11136):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-27 10:23:47.228: E/AndroidRuntime(11136):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-27 10:23:47.228: E/AndroidRuntime(11136):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4960)
05-27 10:23:47.228: E/AndroidRuntime(11136):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-27 10:23:47.228: E/AndroidRuntime(11136):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-27 10:23:47.228: E/AndroidRuntime(11136):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
05-27 10:23:47.228: E/AndroidRuntime(11136):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
05-27 10:23:47.228: E/AndroidRuntime(11136):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-27 10:23:47.228: E/AndroidRuntime(11136): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Null options are not permitted for this Api
05-27 10:23:47.228: E/AndroidRuntime(11136):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.fq.b(Unknown Source)
05-27 10:23:47.228: E/AndroidRuntime(11136):    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$Builder.addApi(Unknown Source)
05-27 10:23:47.228: E/AndroidRuntime(11136):    at com.example.mygoogleplus.GooglePlusMainActivity.onCreate(GooglePlusMainActivity.java:89)
05-27 10:23:47.228: E/AndroidRuntime(11136):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5203)
05-27 10:23:47.228: E/AndroidRuntime(11136):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
05-27 10:23:47.228: E/AndroidRuntime(11136):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2078)`

Answer (score 119, accepted):

The following have worked for me.

Just pass on a single parameter in this manner.

```
.addApi(Plus.API)
```

instead of

```
.addApi(Plus.API, null)
```

**OR**

you could also pass it a PlusOptions object

```
.addApi(Plus.API, Plus.PlusOptions.builder().build())
```

Either of these solutions will work.

Comment: This solved mine as well. I had to edit the GameHelper.java file:

    if (0 != (mRequestedClients & CLIENT_PLUS)) {
        builder.addApi(Plus.API);/*, mPlusApiOptions);*/
        builder.addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN);
    }

Comment: The docs for this G+ stuff are riddled with stupid issues like this. Thanks for covering for them!

Comment: you are great, i am very thankful to you, i was stuck on this since 4 months, and i didn't knew what the actual problem is. thanks a lot man.

Answer (score 3):

You should build Options for that API

```
.addApi(Plus.API, PlusOptions.builder().build())
```

If you use GameHelper - you should call setPlusApiOptions before setup.

```
// Google Play Services
m_GameHelper = new GameHelper(this, GameHelper.CLIENT_GAMES | GameHelper.CLIENT_PLUS);
m_GameHelper.setPlusApiOptions( PlusOptions.builder().build() );
m_GameHelper.setup(this);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(Plus.API)
                .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN) 
                .build();
```

Its worked for me. mGoogleApiClient is a object of GoogleApiClient. Pass Only one parameter into addApi().
 Like

```
.addApi(Plus.API)
```